# Binding multiple values to different variables in c# using for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

How should i bind the values without using index no. as above, how can use   forLoop here if possible. in query i gor 14 rows and 4 columns.

```
public class SLRInvestmentPrev
    {
        [DbCol("BOOK_VALUE")]
        public double BOOK_VALUE { get; set; }
        [DbCol("INSTRUMENT_ID")]
        public int instrument_id { get; set; }
    }
Public void Compute()
    {
var slrinvestmentPrev = Database.BindList<SLRInvestmentPrev>(Transaction, @"Query here");

View["BOOK_VALUE_HTM0"] = slrinvestmentPrev[0].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_HTM1"] =     slrinvestmentPrev[1].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_HTM2"] =  slrinvestmentPrev[2].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_HTM3"] = slrinvestmentPrev[3].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_HFT1"] = slrinvestmentPrev[4].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_HFT2"] = slrinvestmentPrev[5].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_HFT3"] = slrinvestmentPrev[6].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_HFT4"] = slrinvestmentPrev[7].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_HFT5"] = slrinvestmentPrev[8].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_AFS1"] = slrinvestmentPrev[9].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_AFS2"] = slrinvestmentPrev[10].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_AFS3"] = slrinvestmentPrev[11].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_AFS4"] = slrinvestmentPrev[12].BOOK_VALUE;
View["BOOK_VALUE_AFS5"] = slrinvestmentPrev[13].BOOK_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the rule, the 4th item is `BOOK_VALUE_HTM3` and the 5th item is `BOOK_VALUE_HFT1`, so you can't derive the name from the index. What is stored in the `INSTRUMENT_ID`, is that this name?

Comment: View["BOOK_VALUE_HTM3"]  consider it as a variable,in fact all left-sided are variables. which is exactly my question is- how to bind that right side index values to different variables using for loop or is there any way to make code short and being error free if suppose to be rows no are less than hard coded index values?

Answer (score 0):

given your books are HTM0 to AFS5 you could do something like

```
    List<String> booklist = new List<string>(new  String[] { "BOOK_VALUE_HTM0", "BOOK_VALUE_HTM1", "BOOK_VALUE_HTM2",<.....> "BOOK_VALUE_AFS5" } ); // or populate from some other means
    int index = 0;
    foreach (String sbook in booklist)
    {
        View[sbook] = slrinvestmentPrev[index].BOOK_VALUE;
        index++
    }
```

Comment: Great! its shorten my code. Thanx for the quick response.

Comment: If you like it, please put a tick on it

Answer (score 0):

> how to bind that right side index values to different variables using
>   for loop or is there any way to make code short and being error free
>   if suppose to be rows no are less than hard coded index values?

So you need a way to bind your names to the indexes, one way it to use a `Dictionary`:

```
var nameIndexes = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 0, "BOOK_VALUE_HTM0" }, { 1, "BOOK_VALUE_HTM1" }, { 2, "BOOK_VALUE_HTM2" }, { 3, "BOOK_VALUE_HTM3" },
    { 4, "BOOK_VALUE_HFT1" }, { 5, "BOOK_VALUE_HFT2" }, { 6, "BOOK_VALUE_HFT3" }, { 7, "BOOK_VALUE_HFT4" }, { 8, "BOOK_VALUE_HFT5" },
    { 9, "BOOK_VALUE_AFS1" }, { 10, "BOOK_VALUE_AFS2" }, { 11, "BOOK_VALUE_AFS3" }, { 12, "BOOK_VALUE_AFS4" }, { 13, "BOOK_VALUE_AFS5" }
};

for(int i = 0; i < slrinvestmentPrev.Count; i++)
{
    View[nameIndexes[i]] = slrinvestmentPrev[i].BOOK_VALUE;
}
```

If the index always starts with 0 and has no gaps you could also use a `List<string>` or `string[]`.